# How to printf ASCII using argv?

Tags: c, ascii

```
scanf("%c",&c);    
printf("%c",c+1);
```

If take an input of 'a' it prints 'b' as I wanted but if I try to do this it prints a odd question mark.

```
char p[50];
char x = argv[1];
scanf(" %[^\n]s", p);
printf("%c\n", x+p[0]);
```

**As I want to run the programm like ./prog 1 , and 1 will add to the value of the letter as 'a' will become 'b'.
but it prints this: �.**

Comment: try `char x = atoi(argv[1]);`

Comment: ... or `char x = argv[1][0] - '0';`, which only works when passing a one digit number on program start-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `argv[1]` comes from the `main(int argc, char *argv[])` you are using a pointer not a char.

Look the declaration `char *argv[]` it says that `argv` is an array of pointers to char. If you want to get the number passed as string in the first parameter you must use:

```
char p[50];
int x = atoi(argv[1]);
scanf(" %[^\n]s", p);
printf("%c\n", x+p[0]);
```

Comment: @ameyCU: Right now because of your question. It works. Of course there is no check for parameters, so if you call program without a valid argv[1] it will crash. You may want add some sanity checks...

Comment: Well yes , we need to check if `argv` is not any character. Or  `atoi` will just be a jerk.

Comment: Works flawlessly, Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is what you asked for please accept solution.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you are adding char instead of integer. What you have to consider is that e.g. value of '1' (in ASCII 49) is not the same as 1. Also, `argv[1]` is primarily a pointer to char so this should give you a warning that you are making an integer from pointer. Therefore, you have to convert `argv[1]` (in this case an array of chars - string) to integer first. If there is such an argument, of course (needs to be checked before accessing).